# MS Word-like background image in CSS

Tags: css

I'm not sure what the MS Word effect is called, when you set an image as the document's background, where it lowers the opacity and changes the color palette a bit.

Is there any way I could do that in CSS? Or an off-topic question, in case it's not possible, does anyone know the name of the effect?

Image with effect:

[image: image with effect]

Original image (minus the text):

[image: original image]

Comment: @Nenotlep nope. Opacity is not the question here. I know how to set that. It's about the effect as a whole (opacity + color fiddling).

Comment: How about some screenshots of what you're looking for? Not all of us use Word

Comment: @EduardLuca well, how about `rgba()` then if you want to fiddle with the colors as well? See http://css-tricks.com/tinted-images-multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: Could you not set the CSS background-image and opacity on that?

Comment: @onetrickpony added example.

Comment: @Nenotlep, that might be enough, I will try it.

Comment: *'Does anyone know the name of the effect?'*: Washout, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no image professional, but I'd have said the image had a higher saturation and contrast, which can be achieved using the CSS `filter` property. Use `opacity` along with this and you have your effect:

```css
.effect {
    -webkit-filter: contrast(200%) saturate(200%);
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZTgY.jpg">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZTgY.jpg" class="effect" >
```

Alter the values passed to get your desired change.

Note the some-what lack of `filter` [support at the moment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Correct syntax would be `-webkit-filter: contrast(200%) saturate(200%);`

Comment: I love you! Looks amazing.

Comment: Was supposed to say either one of the two. Thanks for taking care of it.